# Laravel Eloquent: Return Array key as the fields ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I execute a query via Laravel's Eloquent ORM, I want to get the row ID as the Array result key, this will make things easier when I want to check something based on an ID (using array_key_exists) or do some look ups (if I need a specific entry from the result array)

Is there any way I can tell Eloquent to set the key to the fields ID?
[image: see image]

Comment: I have to agree you would have to do it yourself. Alternatively you could use `->find($id)` on the collection to find a model by id...

Comment: You have plenty of methods: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html & http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html so you shouldn't need to do it. Eloquent doesn't provide such thing.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can simply do

```
Model::all()->keyBy('category_id');
```

Comment: If you're doing a custom query, you can use it like this: Model::selectRaw(...)->where(...)->groupBy('field')->get()->keyBy('field')->toArray();

Answer (score 36):

Since you have an Eloquent Collection (a [child class](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) of the [generic `Collection` class](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)) you can use the [`getDictionary` method](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_getDictionary). `$collection->getDictionary()` will give you an array of your Category objects keyed by their primary keys.

If you wanted another Collection rather than a native PHP array, you could instead use `$collection->keyBy($property)`. It looks like your primary key is `category_id`, so `$collection->keyBy('category_id')`. You can use that method to key by any arbitrary property, including any get mutators you may have written.

While `getDictionary` is unique to the Eloquent `Collection` extension, `keyBy` is available to all Laravel `Collection` objects. See the [Laravel 4.2 API docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_keyBy) or [Laravel 5.0 API docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_keyBy).

Answer (score 4):

You have a `Support\Collection`/`Database\Eloquent\Collection` you can use the method `lists('id')` to return an array of the id of each of the models within the collection.

Then use `array_combine` to map the keys to the models. The result of which will be an array with the id mapped to their corresponding model.

Answer (score 3):

If you need id as the key, then rely on the Collection:

```
$collection = Model::all();

$collection->getDictionary();

// returns:
array(
  1 => object(Model) ( ... ),
  2 => object(Model) ( ... ),
  ...
  idN => object(Model) ( ... )
);
```

Otherwise, nice or not, you can do this:

```
$keys = $collection->lists('columnName');

$arrayOfModels = array_combine($keys, $collection->getDictionary);
```

Answer (score 1):

`pluck('label','id')` on the get() output is what you're looking for in Laravel 5.8+, which gives you a collection, ready to be `toArray()`ed

eg:

```
$options = \App\DataChoice::where([ 'field_id' => $dataField->id , 'active' => true ])->get()->pluck('label','id')->toArray();
```

I had a similar challenge - I wanted to a PHP array to allow me  to create a  with an  for each choice, with the 's value being the id auto increment column, and the displayed text being the value.